# Proving theorems on relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, relations

I came across the following three statements about relations. I understand why the statements are true, but I am not sure how to demonstrate them mathematically.

In the following, $A,B$ are sets and $R$ is a relation.

(i) $R[A \cup B] = R[A] \cup R[B]$

**Proof**: $A \cup B$ consists of elements both in $A$ and $B$, and thus $R[A \cup B]$ consists of the image of $A \cup B$ under the relation $R$. Both common and uncommon elements of $A$ and $B$ will be present in $A \cup B$, and thus their corresponding images will appear in $R[A \cup B]$.

On the other hand, $R[A] \cup R[B]$ will consists of the elements of $R[A]$ and $R[B]$.

Since the union operation does not lead to loss of elements in a set, we will end up retaining all the common and uncommon elements of the images of sets $A, B$ and $A \cup B$. Thus, ensuring that the left and right hand sides are equal.

(ii) $R[A \cap B] \subseteq R[A] \cap R[B]$

**Proof**: The intersection operation can lead to loss of elements, i.e. elements that are not common in the two sets. Thus the $A \cap B$ can be an empty set. But the images of $R[A]$ and $R[B]$ can have common elements even whem $A$ and $B$ themselves do not have common elements. Thus the set $R[A] \cap R[B]$ will have elements that are images of the common elements of $A$ and $B$, and also the common images of the uncommon terms of $A$ and $B$. Thus, $R[A \cap B]$ will be a subset of $R[A] \cap R[B]$.

(iii) $R[A - B] \supseteq R[A] - R[B]$

**Proof**: The operation can lead to loss of elements. Thus the $A - B$ can be an empty set. But the images of $R[A]$ and $R[B]$ can have common elements even when $A$ and $B$ themselves do not have common elements. Thus the set $R[A] - R[B]$ will not have elements that are the common images of the uncommon elements of $A$ and $B$. On the other hand $R[A-B]$ will maintain those common images of the uncommon elements of $A$. Thus, $R[A] -R[B]$ will be a subset of $R[A-B]$.

For (ii) and (iii) the "subset of" and "superset of" relations will become equality when the $R$ becomes mapping.

I would like to be able to write the above proofs mathematically. How could I do so?

Comment: Is R a function?

Comment: Based on the title, I think we can safely take $R$ to be a relation on the respective sets.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have edited the question to make it more clear. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show $R[A \cup B] = R[A] \cup R[B]$ for a relation $R \subset X \times Y$, $A,B \subset X$, we have to show two inclusions.

So take any $y \in R[A \cup B]$; this means that there exists $x \in A \cup B$ such that $(x,y) \in R$. Then either $x \in A$, and then $y \in R[A]$, or $x \in B$ and then $y \in R[B]$. In either case $y \in R[A] \cup R[B]$, as required. So $R[A \cup B] \subseteq R[A] \cup 
R[B]$.

Reversely, take $y \in R[A] \cup R[B]$. Then $y \in R[A]$ or $y \in R[B]$. In the former case there is some $x \in A$ with $(x,y) \in R$, and in the latter there is some $x \in B$ with $(x,y) \in R$. In either case, $x \in A \cup B$, so $y \in R[A \cup B]$. So $R[A] \cup R[B] \subseteq R[A \cup B]$.

The other cases are handled similarly, but we only have to show one inclusion..

Comment: Thank you. That is very clear.